# a pythonic way of doubling consecutive binary bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a binary list as input, here is an example:-
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

I want to write a function that creates two scores.  a score for the zeros and a score for the ones.

The scoring system is as follows: if two of the same numbers are next to each other, the score doubles in value each time.  So if there are two ones next to each other that is valued as more than if they were separated by a zero.  Two ones next to each other will be valued as 3.  Three ones next to each other will be valued as 7, and so on.
[1, 1]

score
1  2

Total = 1 + 2 = 3

[1, 1 ,1]

Score
1  2  4

Total = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7

So for example with the binary looking list above
the total value of zeros is 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6   (zeros total)

the total value of the ones is 1 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 1 = 9    (ones total)

Example 2:
Input:
[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]

Ones
index 3 = 1, index 4 = 2,  index 6 = 1, index 7 = 2
Ones Total = 1+2+1+2 = 6

Zeros
index 0 = 1, index 1 = 2, index 2 = 4, Index 5 = 1
Zeros Total = 1+2+4+1 = 8

Example 3:
input:  [1,1,1,1]
output:  ones total = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15,  zeros total = 0

Example 4:
input:  [0,0,0,0,1]
output:  zeros total = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15, ones total = 1

So input is a variable length list of ones and zeros
Output is two totals, a total for the zeros, and a total for the ones.

Wondering if there is a fancy short bitwise approach to achieving this in the shortest pythonic code ?

Comment: i don't uderstand your calculations - in first examples you have 10 digits (5 zeros, 5 ones) but you calculated 6 zeros and 9 ones. The other exmaples don't calculate zeros and ones but they convert binary value `1111` to decimal value `15` (or `15 - binary_value`)

Comment: You have the necessary information to create a simple pseudo code that you can convert to python code.  That is the whole point of this exercise.  The SO community can help; but it is not a code writing service.

Comment: or maby you means that `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]` should be treated as binary numbers `[ "0100", "1110", "10" ]` and then you calculate `int("0100", 2) + int("1110", 2) + int("10", 2)`

Comment: I have updated the explanation to have additional examples.  Does this help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's that?

```
from itertools import groupby
input_list =  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
results = [0, 0]  # First value is zeros, second is ones
for key, values in groupby(input_list):
    results[key] += (2**len(tuple(values))) - 1
assert results == [6,9]
```